Existence of periodic orbits with arbitrary small period
Consider the ODE
\begin{align*}
    \begin{cases}
        x'=y\\
        y'=-\sin x+\varepsilon y^3
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
(1) For $\varepsilon>0$, Show that this system has no periodic orbit.
(2) For $\varepsilon=0$, given any small $T>0$, are there periodic orbit with period $T$?
Attempt. The first statement follows from the Poincar'e-Dulac theorem. Set $f(x,y):=(P(x,y),Q(x,y))=(y,-\sin x+\varepsilon y^3)$, then $\mathrm{div}f=P_{x}+Q_{y}=3\varepsilon y^2$ is positive almost everywhere. If there is a periodic orbit $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))$, then $\mathrm{d}x=P\mathrm{d}t, \mathrm{d}y=Q\mathrm{d}t$. Denote the interior of $\gamma$ by $\Omega$, then by Green's formula, we get the following contradiction:
\begin{align*}
    0<\int_{\Omega}\mathrm{div}f=\int_{\gamma}-Q\mathrm{d}x+P\mathrm{d}y=\int_{\gamma}(-QP+PQ)\mathrm{d}t=0.
\end{align*}
For the second statement, I guess this statement is true from the phase portrait.

However, I have no idea about the rigorous proof. Can someone give me some tips or answers？ I would appreciate any answers and comments.

No, it is not true.
You get the pendulum equation $$x''+\sin(x)=0$$ which oscillates with periods close above $2\pi$ for small  amplitudes of $x$.

Thanks for @Lutz Lehmann's insightful comment! Receiving inspiration from Lutz's comment and Draw the period as a function of the energy for the simple pendulum, I came up with a negative proof of the second statement.
Note that $\begin{cases}x'=y\\y'=-\sin x\end{cases}$ is a Hamilton system. We consider the energy $E(x,y):=\frac{1}{2}y^2+(1-\cos x)$, along any trajectory $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))$, we have
\begin{align*}
    E'(t)=\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}E(x(t),y(t))=y(t)y'(t)+\sin x(t) x'(t)=0.
\end{align*}
Therefore, $E$ is constant along any trajectory.
Claim. For any periodic orbit $\gamma(t)$, its period has a lower bound $2\pi$.
Proof. Since $\gamma$ is a periodic orbit, then its interior must contain a singularity. WLOG, assume that $(0,0)$ belongs to the interior of $\gamma$,  thus $\gamma$ must pass through the $x$-axis. We can assume that $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ with $\gamma(0)=(x_{0},0)$ for some $x_{0}\in (0,\pi)$. Since $E$ is constant along $\gamma$, then
\begin{align*}
    E(x(t),y(t))\equiv E(x_{0},0)\ &\Longrightarrow \ \dfrac{1}{2}y^2+(1-\cos x)=1-\cos x_{0}\\
    &\Longrightarrow \ y^2=2(\cos x-\cos x_{0}).
\end{align*}
Since $y=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}$, then $\mathrm{d}t=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{y}$. By the symmetry of $\gamma$, we get
\begin{align*}
T=\int_{0}^{T}\mathrm{d}t=4\int_{0}^{x_{0}}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{2(\cos x-\cos x_{0})}}.
\end{align*}
Introducing a new variable $\theta$, such that
\begin{align*}
    \sin\theta=\dfrac{\sin(x/2)}{\sin(x_{0}/2)},
\end{align*}
now the above integral becomes
\begin{align*}
    T=4\int_{0}^{x_{0}}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{2(\cos x-\cos x_{0})}}=4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\cos x/2}\ge 2\pi.
\end{align*}
The last inequality is because $x\in(0,x_{0})\subset (0,\pi)$, then $0<\cos x/2<1$, thus $\frac{1}{\cos x/2}>1$.
